# Fixing remote IP and REMOTE_ADDR with mod_rpaf / mod_remoteip doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, nginx, php-5.6, apache2.4

So I'm migrating some legacy PHP project from an old server to a new one.
New server is using Debian 10 / Nginx / Apache 2.4 / PHP 5.6.40

I've set up everything like I'm used to, using mod_rpaf to override the remote IP address with the one coming from nginx in X-Real-IP.
I see the correct address in `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']` in PHP, but `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is still '127.0.0.1'

Things I tried already:

- commenting out `<IfModule rpaf_module>` in the rpaf.conf file (some old answers suggested that the module name could be incorrect);
- changing configuration directives from `RPAFenable`, etc. to `RPAF_Enable` and so on - apache refuses to start so obviously the `RPAFenable` format is correct;
- disabling mod_rpaf and using mod_remoteip instead - no effect;
- using PHP's auto_prepend_file ini file option to replace REMOTE_ADDR with HTTP_X_REAL_IP - doesn't have any effect despite code being executed (checked it with `echo '1';`).

So I'm quite in a dead end and see no other option but just using `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'] || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` ugly constructions everywhere in code...

But I still hope there's something I'm missing.

**Update:** In fact, auto_prepend_file option worked, but feels kinda hacky... I'd still like to find a better option.

Comment: what can you see in apache logs? is %a displaying the needed ip?

Comment: No, it's 127.0.0.1. %h does display correct one though.